# Finding python site-package directory in debian container?

Tags: python, docker, debian

I have a docker container created with:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/base:0.202.2-debian-11

RUN sudo apt update && \
    sudo apt -y upgrade && \
    sudo apt -y install graphviz && \
    sudo apt -y install python3-venv python3-pip && \
    python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install flake8 wheel
```

and I'm seeing unexpected results from standard ways of finding the site-packages directory.

The correct location is `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages`, and contains the flake8 package (and mccabe, pyflakes, pycodestyle that it has as dependencies) installed in the `RUN` command. Running e.g. `pip install magicmethods` in the container also installs packages in this directory.

However, `sysconfig` gives:

```
>>> import sysconfig
>>> sysconfig.get_paths()['purelib']
'/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages'
```

which is a directory that doesn't exist.

`distutils` gives:

```
>>> from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
>>> get_python_lib()
'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages'
```

which does exist (and contains lsb_release.py, setuptools and wheel), but isn't the correct directory in this context.

Am I using the wrong code to find site-packages?

Comment: `__file__` might be useful - especially if there are packages installed in different folders. E.g., `pyflakes.__file__`

Comment: I suppose I could do `import pip;print(pip.__file__.split("pip")[0]` but it seems awfully hacky when Python has libraries that should tell me directly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function I was missing was `site.getsitepackages()`, although that returns a list containing potentially non-existing directories.

My code tries to find package names for installed modules - i.e. you list

```
django-cms
```

in requirements.txt, but to import the installed module you need:

```
import cms
```

so the working code is (only the part before the second for-loop is strictly needed to answer the question...):

```
import site

def find_package_names():
    res = {}

    site_package_dirs = [site.getusersitepackages()]
    site_package_dirs += site.getsitepackages()

    for site_packages in reversed(site_package_dirs):
        if not os.path.isdir(site_packages):
            continue

        # site_package_dirs now contains a list of existing directories

        for pth in os.listdir(site_packages):
            if not pth.endswith('.dist-info'):
                continue
            pkgname = pth.split('-', 1)[0].replace('_', '-')
            top_level_fname = os.path.join(site_packages, pth, 'top_level.txt')
            if not os.path.exists(top_level_fname):
                continue

            with open(top_level_fname) as fp:
                modnames = fp.read().split()

            for modname in modnames:
                modname = modname.replace('/', '.')
                res[modname] = pkgname

    return res
```